# Maintain a changing copy of data in a class in Java

Tags: java, class, copy, composition

In `Java`, I have a data store class, which maintains two versions of data of the same type but of possibly different value. Is there any better way to represent a copy fields? Tried to use composition `BuildingMaterials copy = new BuildingMaterials();` but this translates into infinite recursion and so goes out of memory. Objects of class `BuildingMaterials` are used in the hash table, so I need fast access to normal fields and their copy and so encapsulate all of them inside one class.

```
    static class BuildingMaterials {
            Date creationDate;
            int bricks;
            int sand;
            // data copy
            Date copy_creationDate;
            int copy_bricks;
            int copy_sand;
            // BuildingMaterials copy = new BuildingMaterials(); // fails
    }
```

Creating two hash tables with the same keys having data and its copy separately in each of them is not a solution!

Comment: Maintain the copy in another class

Answer (score 0):

One solution would be to create another class called CopiedBuildingMaterials, which then contains two instances of BuildingMaterials: the original and the copied versions.

```
class CopiedBuildingMaterials{
   BuildingMaterials original;
   BuildingMaterials copied;
}

class BuildingMaterials {
   Date creationDate;
   int bricks;
   int sand;
}
```